# How does the CPU limitation on Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation work?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, installation, hp-proliant, limitations

I'am little bit confused about the CPU limitation of Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation. The Server is installed on a HP proliant DL380 Gen9 with 2x 6-core CPUs, with the HP provisioning Tool I do install the Windows Foundation Server on this machine. After the installation process I can see that 2 CPUs are active, but only 4 Cores per CPU.

In the [technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj679892.aspx) is written that the Limitation on this Windows Server edition is 1 CPU but with unlimited Cores. But on my System are 2 CPUs active with limited to 4 Cores per Socket.

Here you can see the Edition is set to foundation but I can see 2 CPUs

[image: taskmanager]

[image]

What is now the right limitation of this edition?

*UPDATE* 
I can reproduce it, if I install from the ISO directly than I must type a Key but with the HP provisioning tool I insert the key after the Installation, maybe HP use any generic Key for the installation. The installed OS told me it is a not activated Foundation server and if I type my right key the limitation of the cores still exist. So the next step will be to find out the generic key of the provisioning tools and retry it with a normal ISO installation.

Comment: Un-activated foundation server deployment supports just one CPU at a time, always use OEM or generic ISO.

Comment: But the activated Version of Foundationserver also support one CPU if I install without the intelligent provisioning of HP, I think while the installation HP use a masterkey and while the activation of the Server the limitation is away.